# Android) Why does DiffUtil have max size constraints?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I read the following sentence in the [RecyclerView DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil) reference.

> Due to implementation constraints, the max size of the list can be 2^26.

I wonder why it's `2^26` but I can't find out why so I ask.
I would be very grateful if you could answer.

Comment: because it depends on diff algorithm if your list reaches to 2^26 item it can make application ANR (Android Not Responding)

Comment: @CôngHải Thank you for your fast reply! Does that mean this constraint will be removed if I deal with diffutil in the background thread?

Comment: Actually, it can. but final when you call dispatch update, you have to transform all items list to UI Thread. 2^26 is huge data.

Comment: @CôngHải I see. Thanks for telling me